# How do you intall GHC 7.8.3 on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to install GhC 7.8.3 on mac os and that's driving me mad.

What should I do ?

I've downloaded the binary installation from [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_3#macosx_x86_64). First I need to do `sudo make install` instead of `install`. Is that normal ?

Then it stop with the following error message :

```
/usr/bin/gcc -E  -m64 -undef -traditional -Wno-invalid-pp-token -Wno-unicode -
Wno-trigraphs -P -DINSTALLING -DLIB_DIR='"/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.3"' -DINCLUDE
_DIR='"/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.3/include"' -DPAPI_INCLUDE_DIR="" -DPAPI_LIB_DIR
="" -DFFI_INCLUDE_DIR= -DFFI_LIB_DIR= '-DFFI_LIB="Cffi"' -x c -Iincludes -Iinc
ludes/dist -Iincludes/dist-derivedconstants/header -Iincludes/dist-ghcconstant
s/header rts/package.conf.in -o rts/dist/package.conf.install.raw
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-invalid-pp-token"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unicode"
make[1]: *** [rts/dist/package.conf.install] Error 1
```

I tried downloading the [ghc-clang-wrapper](https://gist.github.com/mzero/7245290/download#). But that doesn't change anything. It complains about haskell platform not being installed so I changed the setting file manually, but still no result.

Also, that might be a daft question, if it's a binary package why is trying to compile stuff ?

Comment: Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). It's as simple as `brew install ghc` then.

Comment: Last time I tried homebrew it only had ghc 7.8.2 not 7.8.3. Then I tried to revert to 7.6.3 and since that my version of Homebrew is corrupted and I can use it anymore.

Comment: It's not actually compiling C. GHC is using the C preprocessor as a macro language for its config files (e.g. see `rts/package.conf.in`). What `gcc --version` do you have? You might need to upgrade to a newer Xcode/CLI tools with a newer clang.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9257

A workaround which seems to work for me is to edit `mk/config.mk`, removing the two offending flags from `RAWCPP_FLAGS`.

Update: Actually, it looks like this may not work hard enough, since this caused my GHC just to fail later. A more complete workaround is to create a file named gcc with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
os.execv("/usr/bin/gcc", ["/usr/bin/gcc"] + [i for i in sys.argv[1:] if i != "-Wno-invalid-pp-token" and i != "-Wno-unicode"])
```

Replace both instances of `/usr/bin/gcc` if your GCC is in an unusual place. Chmod it executable. Now, when configuring your bindist, pass the configure flag `--with-gcc=/path/to/your/gcc`. This will strip out the warning flags and make things work.